# How does the following va_arg macro work?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, comma-operator

I am reading a stdarg.h (link below) header file which defines the va_arg macro as follows

```
/*
 * Increment ap to the next argument in the list while returing a
 * pointer to what ap pointed to first, which is of type t.
 *
 * We cast to void* and then to t* because this avoids a warning about
 * increasing the alignment requirement.
 */
#define va_arg(ap, t)                   \
 (((ap) = (ap) + __va_argsiz(t)),       \
  *((t*) (void*) ((ap) - __va_argsiz(t))))
```

The line

```
((ap) = (ap) + __va_argsiz(t))
```

reassigns the value of ap however I don't understand the purpose of the comma or the line

```
*((t*) (void*) ((ap) - __va_argsiz(t)))
```

[Link to stdarg.h file](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/cis/software/g77-mingw32/include/stdarg.h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to return to the caller what `ap` has been pointed to, *and* advance `ap`. An equivalent would be

```
    old_ap = ap
    ap = ap + argsiz
    return *old_ap
```

However, that would require an extra variable, which is very hard (if possible) deal with in a macro in a portable way. Instead, the macro relies on a comma expression. It advances `ap`, and then computes its old value, which becomes a value of the comma expression, that is of the entire macro.

Comment: I have never seen a comma used like this, what is it called when a comma is used like this?

Comment: As I have only ever seen a comma used as a separator

Comment: @duper21 See `comma operator` in any C textbook.

Comment: Does this mean the compiler executes two statements on the same line?

Comment: @duper21 Same line is irrelevant. The expression `a, b` yields the value of `b`.

Comment: So the second statement returns the value whilst statements before are only executed ?

Comment: @duper21 Correct. However, don't confuse comma in a comma operator with the comma in an argument list. They are very different beasts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198378/discussion-between-duper21-and-user58697).

Comment: There are at least three different uses of the comma character in C: as a separator in declarations like `int a, b;`, as a separator between the arguments in function calls, and as the comma operator, which is what we're looking at here.

Answer (score 2):

There is an expression with the comma operator.

The first sub-expression

```
(((ap) = (ap) + __va_argsiz(t))
```

increase the pointer `ap`.

The second sub-expression

```
*((t*) (void*) ((ap) - __va_argsiz(t))))
```

returns the value pointed to by the pointer `ap` before its increment.

If you have a question relative to the comma operator then it allows to combine several full expressions in one expression.

Consider for example the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };

    size_t i = 0;

    printf( "%d\n", ( i++, a[i] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2
```

Here the argument of the `printf` call is an expression with the comma operator.

Or a more interesting example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };

    size_t i = 0;

    printf( "%d\n", a[i] ), i++, printf( "%d\n", a[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
2
```

Here the expression statement

```
    printf( "%d\n", a[i] ), i++, printf( "%d\n", a[i] );
```

contains an expression with using two comma operators.

Comment: _increase the pointer_ `ap` with the size of the argument type.

Comment: What is the use of the comma?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have a `char *` pointer `p` that points to some characters.  Suppose I want to return the character pointed to by `p`, and simultaneously increment `p` to point to the next character.  That's easy, that's just `*p++` — a totally basic operation in C.

And because of the way pointer arithmetic works, if I have an `int *` pointer `ip` that points to some integers, I can do exactly the same thing.  `*ip++` returns the integer pointed to by `ip`, and it increments `ip` to point to the next integer.  Crucially, if we were to look at the actual value of the pointer `ip` both before and after this operation, we would find that it had been incremented by `sizeof(int)`, not just by 1.

Now, `va_arg(ap, t)` is sort of like `*ip++`.  It returns the argument "pointed to" by `ap`, and it increments `ap` to point to the next thing in the list.  *But*, and this is a very big "but", we don't necessarily want to increment by `sizeof(int)`.  We want to increment by `sizeof(t)`, where `t` is whatever the caller told us is the currently-expected argument type in the list.  (We can assume that the actual type of the pointer `ap` is `char *`, so that it increments by individual bytes, so that it's meaningful to add `sizeof(t)` to it.)

So what we, sort of, want is the effect of `*(ap += sizeof(t))`.  But `+=` gives you preincrement, and we want postincrement.  And while C gives you the handy distinction between preincrement `++` and postincement `++`, the `+=` operator is always preincrement.  There's no postincrement form.

So the code you've shown for `va_arg` has to simulate a postincrement `+=` the hard way, using two separate expressions separated by a comma operator.  First it adds `sizeof(int)` to `ap` using the subexpression `(ap) = (ap) + __va_argsiz(t)`, and then it returns what `ap` used to point to by subtracting the size it just added: `*((t*) (void*) ((ap) - __va_argsiz(t)))`.

The comma operator always does two things in sequence: it does the first thing and throws away the result, then it does the second thing and returns the second thing's value.  This definition of `v_arg` has been arranged to take advantage of that definition.  We don't care about the value of the first subexpression — the point of the first expression is its side effect, of adding something to `ap`.  What we need the value of (that is, to be `va_arg`'s value) is the second subexpression.

(In other words, based on the way the comma operator works, it's not possible to write an expression that first returns what `ap` points to, then adds something to `ap`.  So the author of this `va_arg` macro had no choice but to do the addition a bit too early, meaning that it had to be counteracted by the subtraction in the second half.)

There's some other magic going on in this definition of `va_arg` — which is hardly surprising, as it's a pretty magical macro! — but this should at least explain what the comma operator is doing there.